# discord.py Копирование ID всех участников сервера

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я делал функцию для своего бота копирующую ID всех участников сервера, однако копирует лишь один ID. В чем проблема? По циклу же вроде всё сделано правильно. Вот код:

```
@client.command(aliases=['id_copy'])
async def id_all(ctx):


    start = discord.Embed(
        title = '⌚ | Начало копирования ID',
        description = f'`Подождите, идёт процесс копирования ID... Скорость завершения зависит от количества участников на сервере.`',
        color = 0x02d800
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=start)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Неудачное копирование...',
        description = '`Произошла ошибка при распаковке файла, пожалуйста проверьте код селф-бота.`',
        color = 0xff0000
    )

    for m in ctx.guild.members:

        try:
            wich open('file_name','a') as f:
               f.write(f'{m.id}\n')

        except:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            break

    top = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Успешное копирование',
        description = '`ID участников данного сервера успешно скопировано в определенный файл. `',
        color = 0x02d800
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=top)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бот видит только сам себя. Для того, чтобы он видел всех участников нужно включить `Member Intent` на https://discord.com/developers/ (во вкладке Bot) и в коде (при создании бота).
[image: .]

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
my_bot = commands.Bot('!', intents=intents)
```

И теперь можно использовать `ctx.guild.members`

или

```
async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=1000):
    print(member.name)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь :)