# Как сделать рассылку всем участникам дискорд сервера? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

**Помогите пожалуйста!**

Как сделать что бы discord боте при вводе определённой команды рассылает всем участникам сервера в личные сообщения информацию которую мы указали при вводе команды

Написать надо на python

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context, message: str):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.send(f'{member.mention}, {message}')
        except:
            pass
```

**Коги**

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx: commands.Context, message: str):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.send(f'{member.mention}, {message}')
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Способ, который подходит, если у вас `ctx`:

```py
@bot.command()
async def guild_message(ctx):
    for Every_Member in ctx.guild.members:
        if Every_Member.bot != True:
            await Every_Member.send('Ваше сообщение тут')
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот так. Но перед этим нужно включить [Member Intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1368638/discord-py-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-id-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/1368697#1368697) чтобы бот мог видеть всех участников сервера.

```
@commands.command()
async def guild_message(self, ctx: commands.Context, message: str):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        user = await self.bot.fetch_user(user_id=member.id)
        if not user.bot:
            await user.send(message)
```